# readmore сделать плавным

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как добавить анимацию при раскрывании и сворачивании блока ?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.content_toggle').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const $link = $(event.target);
    const $content = $link.prev('.content_block');

    $content.toggleClass('hide');

    const htmlLink = $content.hasClass('hide') ? 'More' : 'Less';
    $link.html(htmlLink);
  });
});
```

```css
.content_block {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.content_block.hide {
  height: 150px;
}

.content_block.hide:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff 75%)
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #777;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.6;
}


/* Кнопка */

.content_toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #672cc5;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #32145a;
}

.content_toggle:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #7c4acc;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #32145a;
}

.content_toggle:active {
  background: #34106d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content_block hide">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In in libero cursus, placerat magna in, malesuada ligula. Proin tellus lacus, tempor in est sodales, elementum fringilla tellus. Donec dignissim elit arcu, et tempor nunc cursus at. Phasellus
    non commodo lacus, non tempus mi. Donec mattis eros aamet volutpat. Fusce porttitor leo non erat gravida, ac pulvinar leo congue. Praesent felis eros, hendrerit quis dui in, consequat accumsan enim. Curabitur ultricies vel sapien ut consequat</p>
  <p>Ut sed laoreet mi, finibus auctor sapien. Nam a nisl maximus, volutpat dui bibendum, suscipit mi. Quisque porttitor sapien ut nulla porta, id faucibus est lobortis. Morbi volutpat non turpis eu tincidunt. Donec gravida felis sem, at vestibulum quam
    congue in. Suspendisse lacinia eget risus a dignissim. Etiam condimentum dapibus tortor sit amet volutpat. Fusce porttitor leo non erat gravida, ac pulvinar leo congue. Praesent felis eros, hendrerit quis dui in, consequat accumsan enim. Curabitur
    ultricies vel sapien ut consequat.</p>
  <p>Nulla tempus eleifend erat, ut vulputate erat tempus et. Integer ultricies elit nisi, vel lacinia dui molestie at. Cras vel feugiat tortor. Suspendisse vulputate, lorem non mollis bibendum, lorem elit aliquet lorem, sit amet euismod metus lacus nec
    mauris. Mauris cursus gravida ultrices. Cras risus metus, blandit placerat vehicula quis, ultrices vel est. Praeent accumsan suscipit enim, vel placerat metus.</p>
</div>
<a class="content_toggle" href="#">More</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JS, max-height и CSS-переменные...

```js
let aMore = document.querySelectorAll('.content_toggle');
aMore.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let elContent = this.previousElementSibling;
    elContent.style.setProperty('--hcb', `${elContent.scrollHeight}px`);
    elContent.classList.toggle('hide');
    this.innerText = elContent.classList.contains('hide') ? 'More' : 'Hide';
  });
});
```

```css
.content_block {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: var(--hcb, 150px);
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.content_block.hide {
  max-height: 150px;
}
.content_block.hide::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff 75%)
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #777;
}

/* Кнопка */
.content_toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #32145a;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #672cc5;
  color: #fff;
}
.content_toggle:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #32145a;
  background: #7c4acc;
  color: #fff;
}
.content_toggle:active {
  background: #34106d;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_block hide">
  <h3>1</h3><hr>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In in libero cursus, placerat magna in, malesuada ligula. Proin tellus lacus, tempor in est sodales, elementum fringilla tellus. Donec dignissim elit arcu, et tempor nunc cursus at. Phasellus non commodo lacus, non tempus mi. Donec mattis eros a porta ullamcorper. Pellentesque at ullamcorper turpis. Aliquam non semper ligula, sed porttitor nulla. Donec a elit accumsan, egestas urna ut, elementum ex. Cras vitae elit nec tortor luctus fermentum. Maecenas et orci in mi venenatis feugiat in sed lectus.</p>
  <p>Ut sed laoreet mi, finibus auctor sapien. Nam a nisl maximus, volutpat dui bibendum, suscipit mi. Quisque porttitor sapien ut nulla porta, id faucibus est lobortis. Morbi volutpat non turpis eu tincidunt. Donec gravida felis sem, at vestibulum quam congue in. Suspendisse lacinia eget risus a dignissim. Etiam condimentum dapibus tortor sit amet volutpat. Fusce porttitor leo non erat gravida, ac pulvinar leo congue. Praesent felis eros, hendrerit quis dui in, consequat accumsan enim. Curabitur ultricies vel sapien ut consequat.</p>
  <p>Nulla tempus eleifend erat, ut vulputate erat tempus et. Integer ultricies elit nisi, vel lacinia dui molestie at. Cras vel feugiat tortor. Suspendisse vulputate, lorem non mollis bibendum, lorem elit aliquet lorem, sit amet euismod metus lacus nec mauris. Mauris cursus gravida ultrices. Cras risus metus, blandit placerat vehicula quis, ultrices vel est. Praeent accumsan suscipit enim, vel placerat metus.</p><hr>
</div>
<a class="content_toggle" href="#">More</a>
<div class="content_block hide">
  <h3>2</h3><hr>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In in libero cursus, placerat magna in, malesuada ligula. Proin tellus lacus, tempor in est sodales, elementum fringilla tellus. Donec dignissim elit arcu, et tempor nunc cursus at. Phasellus non commodo lacus, non tempus mi. Donec mattis eros a porta ullamcorper. Pellentesque at ullamcorper turpis. Aliquam non semper ligula, sed porttitor nulla. Donec a elit accumsan, egestas urna ut, elementum ex. Cras vitae elit nec tortor luctus fermentum. Maecenas et orci in mi venenatis feugiat in sed lectus.</p>
  <p>Ut sed laoreet mi, finibus auctor sapien. Nam a nisl maximus, volutpat dui bibendum, suscipit mi. Quisque porttitor sapien ut nulla porta, id faucibus est lobortis. Morbi volutpat non turpis eu tincidunt. Donec gravida felis sem, at vestibulum quam congue in. Suspendisse lacinia eget risus a dignissim. Etiam condimentum dapibus tortor sit amet volutpat. Fusce porttitor leo non erat gravida, ac pulvinar leo congue. Praesent felis eros, hendrerit quis dui in, consequat accumsan enim. Curabitur ultricies vel sapien ut consequat.</p>
  <p>Nulla tempus eleifend erat, ut vulputate erat tempus et. Integer ultricies elit nisi, vel lacinia dui molestie at. Cras vel feugiat tortor. Suspendisse vulputate, lorem non mollis bibendum, lorem elit aliquet lorem, sit amet euismod metus lacus nec mauris. Mauris cursus gravida ultrices. Cras risus metus, blandit placerat vehicula quis, ultrices vel est. Praeent accumsan suscipit enim, vel placerat metus.</p><hr>
</div>
<a class="content_toggle" href="#">More</a>
<div class="content_block hide">
  <h3>3</h3><hr>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In in libero cursus, placerat magna in, malesuada ligula. Proin tellus lacus, tempor in est sodales, elementum fringilla tellus. Donec dignissim elit arcu, et tempor nunc cursus at. Phasellus non commodo lacus, non tempus mi. Donec mattis eros a porta ullamcorper. Pellentesque at ullamcorper turpis. Aliquam non semper ligula, sed porttitor nulla. Donec a elit accumsan, egestas urna ut, elementum ex. Cras vitae elit nec tortor luctus fermentum. Maecenas et orci in mi venenatis feugiat in sed lectus.</p>
  <p>Ut sed laoreet mi, finibus auctor sapien. Nam a nisl maximus, volutpat dui bibendum, suscipit mi. Quisque porttitor sapien ut nulla porta, id faucibus est lobortis. Morbi volutpat non turpis eu tincidunt. Donec gravida felis sem, at vestibulum quam congue in. Suspendisse lacinia eget risus a dignissim. Etiam condimentum dapibus tortor sit amet volutpat. Fusce porttitor leo non erat gravida, ac pulvinar leo congue. Praesent felis eros, hendrerit quis dui in, consequat accumsan enim. Curabitur ultricies vel sapien ut consequat.</p>
  <p>Nulla tempus eleifend erat, ut vulputate erat tempus et. Integer ultricies elit nisi, vel lacinia dui molestie at. Cras vel feugiat tortor. Suspendisse vulputate, lorem non mollis bibendum, lorem elit aliquet lorem, sit amet euismod metus lacus nec mauris. Mauris cursus gravida ultrices. Cras risus metus, blandit placerat vehicula quis, ultrices vel est. Praeent accumsan suscipit enim, vel placerat metus.</p><hr>
</div>
<a class="content_toggle" href="#">More</a>
```

> *Ну, достучался,*
> *А дальше?.. JS?*
> *jQuery - убогая штука.*

Comment: Получилось, только проблема в том что когда я сворачиваю блок он меня к нижним блокам скидывает...(

Comment: @BekzodM: каким таким нижним? В вопросе только один блок.

Comment: Я использую ваш код у себя в проекте и у меня там не один блок) Если вам не трудно помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: @BekzodM: я продублировал блоки в примере - попробуйте и уточните в чём проблема, если здесь происходит то же, что у Вас в проекте.

Comment: Здесь нормально работает, у меня совсем по другому( Может скину Вам папку,  посмотрите?

Comment: @BekzodM: не нужно ничего скидывать, а нужно внимательно копировать. В стили заглядывали? Там парочка изменений тоже.

Comment: Сделал все в точности как у вас! Ладно что-нибудь придумаю, спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 2):

Не обязательно для этого использовать анимацию `jquery`. Большинство современных браузеров поддерживают свойство `transition` в `css`. Для примера добавил в класс `content_block` высоту 500 пикселей (для того что бы анимация работала, нужно четко указать начало и конец, в данном случаи высота: от 150 до 500) ну и это самое главное `transition` который и отвечает за анимацию. Выставляйте как Вам нужно.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.content_toggle').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();

     const $link= $(event.target);
     const $content = $link.prev('div.content_block');
   
     $content.toggleClass('hide');

     const htmlLink  = $content.hasClass('hide') ? 'More' :  'Hide'; 
     $link.html(htmlLink);  
  });               
});
```

```css
.content_block {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.content_block.hide {
  height: 150px;
}
.content_block.hide:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #fff 75%)
}
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #777;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

/* Кнопка */
.content_toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #672cc5;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #32145a;
}
.content_toggle:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #7c4acc;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #32145a;
}
.content_toggle:active {
  background: #34106d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content_block hide">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In in libero cursus, placerat magna in, malesuada ligula. Proin tellus lacus, tempor in est sodales, elementum fringilla tellus. Donec dignissim elit arcu, et tempor nunc cursus at. Phasellus non commodo lacus, non tempus mi. Donec mattis eros a porta ullamcorper. Pellentesque at ullamcorper turpis. Aliquam non semper ligula, sed porttitor nulla. Donec a elit accumsan, egestas urna ut, elementum ex. Cras vitae elit nec tortor luctus fermentum. Maecenas et orci in mi venenatis feugiat in sed lectus.</p>
  <p>Ut sed laoreet mi, finibus auctor sapien. Nam a nisl maximus, volutpat dui bibendum, suscipit mi. Quisque porttitor sapien ut nulla porta, id faucibus est lobortis. Morbi volutpat non turpis eu tincidunt. Donec gravida felis sem, at vestibulum quam congue in. Suspendisse lacinia eget risus a dignissim. Etiam condimentum dapibus tortor sit amet volutpat. Fusce porttitor leo non erat gravida, ac pulvinar leo congue. Praesent felis eros, hendrerit quis dui in, consequat accumsan enim. Curabitur ultricies vel sapien ut consequat.</p>
  <p>Nulla tempus eleifend erat, ut vulputate erat tempus et. Integer ultricies elit nisi, vel lacinia dui molestie at. Cras vel feugiat tortor. Suspendisse vulputate, lorem non mollis bibendum, lorem elit aliquet lorem, sit amet euismod metus lacus nec mauris. Mauris cursus gravida ultrices. Cras risus metus, blandit placerat vehicula quis, ultrices vel est. Praeent accumsan suscipit enim, vel placerat metus.</p>
</div>

<a class="content_toggle" href="#">More</a>
```

Comment: А если контента больше чем на 500px ?

Comment: если высота динамическая, тогда лучше использовать max-height

Comment: Тоже получилось, только та же проблема при сворачивании скидывает к нижним блокам...(